# Erlang: Converting TCP sent string into its proper form e.g. <<"SomeString">> to "SomeString"?

Tags: string, tcp, formatting, erlang, client-server

I have a client and a server and I use the client to send a string such as `"Hello"` and it shows up on the server side as `<<"Hello">>`. Is there a way to simply convert `<<"Hello">>` back to `"Hello"`? I tried to use,

```
String = io_lib:format("~p",[StringIn]),
            lists:flatten(String),
```

But that made the format `<<"Hello">>` turn into `[[60,60,"\"Hello\"",62,62]]`...

Heres the code by the way:

```
-module(ss1).
-compile(export_all).
-import(lists, [reverse/1]).

client() ->
    {ok, Socket} =  gen_tcp:connect("localhost", 2345,[binary, {packet, 4}]),
    ok = gen_tcp:send(Socket, "Hello"),
    receive
    {tcp,Socket,String} ->
        io:format("Client received = ~p~n",[String]),       
        io:format("Client result = ~p~n",[String]),
        gen_tcp:close(Socket)
    end.

server() ->
    {ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(2345, [binary, {packet, 4},  {reuseaddr, true}, {active, true}]),
    {ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen),
    gen_tcp:close(Listen),  
    loop(Socket).

loop(Socket) ->
    receive
    {tcp,Socket,String} ->      
        io:format("Server received String = ~p~n",[String]),            
        io:format("Server replying String = ~p~n",[String]),
        gen_tcp:send(Socket, String), 
        loop(Socket);
    {tcp_closed, Socket} ->
        io:format("Server socket closed~n")
    end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function - binary_to_list from erlang module.

```
  Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)

1> B = <<"Hello">>.
<<"Hello">>
2> erlang:binary_to_list(B).
"Hello"
3>
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason is this line:

```
{ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(2345, [binary, {packet, 4},  {reuseaddr, true}, {active, true}]),
```

Specifically, the atom `binary` passed in the options. If you pass `list` instead, you'll get a regular string. See the [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#listen-2) for `gen_tcp:listen/2`.

The reason the following code didn't work:

```
String = io_lib:format("~p",[StringIn]),
lists:flatten(String), ...
```

Is that `lists:flatten/1` doesn't actually *change* `String`; it returns a new list that is the result of flattening its argument. This would have worked:

```
lists:flatten(io_lib:format("~p", [StringIn])).
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to print your binary using `io:format` or `io_lib:format`, you can use the `~s` format specifier:

```
1> MyBinary = <<"Hello">>.
<<"Hello">>
2> io:format("MyBinary is '~s'~n", [MyBinary]).
MyBinary is 'Hello'
ok
```